# How to access virtual guest centos on windowsxp remotely

Tags: windows, centos, xen, selinux

I have installed CentOS(domain 0) as a Base OS then using XEN tool virt-manager, I have created another CentOS5(domU) as virtual guestOS.

I can easily access base CentOS(domain 0) by windows remotely using putty and vnc viewer. But 
I cann't able to access virtual guest CentOS5(domU) directly by windows putty or vnc.
But I have enable port of tcp/udp in 5901 under virtual domU OS no use for me.

Please help me how to access virtual guest centos remotely???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*netstat -tlnp|grep -w 5901* on your Dom0 will propably show you that that port is listening on 127.0.0.1? You can change that, if you like to.

But anyway - why do you need graphical access to the DomU with vnc?

Set up sshd on your DomU and use putty with X-forwarding and X-ming on your XP client.
That way you will get a working X11-session in windows.